# Asking for confirmartion on node creation

Tags: forms

I want ask for confirmation if a duplicate node is getting created. But how do I do it?

I know how to do it if I'm creating the form myself but in node creation I'm not creating the form.

I also know Drupal confirm_form, how "storage" is used in multistep forms. But how to use it along with the code which is not mine. Where to plug it?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate?  Duplicate body content? Duplicate titles? Duplicate timestamps? Duplicate all of the above?  All nodes get a unique ID so technically there will be no true duplicates.  Though as @paul-m stated below, if your checking for uniqueness when submitting new content it is likely hook_node_validate is what you need.

Comment: The node contains duplicate data like someone else trying to create a Person node which already exists and I want to warn before creating similar looking Person node. Ex: If someone try to create same name, sex and date of birth Person then I'd want to flag it as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

@AgA: "I want ask for confirmation if a duplicate node is getting created. But how do I do it?"

The way you do it is to validate any new node added by a user against existing nodes.

Towards this end, [`hook_node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) is your friend. :-) You'd make a module that implements `hook_node_validate()`, and within that function do a query using the data the user input. If you find similar nodes that already exist, you can `form_set_error()` an error message. Click through to the API site and there's even some sample code.

Comment: This is not what I've asked.

Comment: It's not entirely what you asked for but it's the most critical component.  When you implement the hook you need to somehow gather all additional content of the same type and compare it against the node passed in as the argument with whatever logic you desire.

Comment: I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)() to modify an already built form.  Here you can include your custom validation function to insert the required code.

From your second sentence, I understand that this isn't necessary but for those looking to implement validation functions using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() here are a few resources to check out.

- See the [Form API Quickstart Guide's](http://drupal.org/node/751826) section on form validation.
- [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) project for Drupal developers.

You may even be able to use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module with a bit of custom PHP code for the condition component of your rule.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know all this. I've got an idea. In case of validation error with "duplicate Person being created..." and I'll store a flag in storage. And in form_alter if this flag is found then I'd attach another button "Resubmit". This should work out, let me see